# Observable/Observer not working?

Tags: java, android, observer-pattern, observable, observers

I tried implementing a static Observable in my Application subclass, but it's not working. No exceptions or error messages, but my update() callback doesn't get called.

**MyApplication.java**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application{
    public static Observable appObserver = new Observable();

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();        
    }

}
```

**Foo.java**

```
MyApplication.appObserver.notifyObservers( "Hello world" );
```

**BarFragment.java**

```
public class BarFragment extends Fragment implements Observer{

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);                
        MyApplication.appObserver.addObserver(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {       
        MyApplication.appObserver.deleteObserver(this);
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    public void update(Observable observable, Object data) {
        Log.i("BarFragment", data.toString()); // Should log, but doesn't
    }

}
```

What's more, I tried scribbling down a simple Observable of my own, and then everything worked like a charm with just substituting `public static Observable appObserver = new Observable();` with `public static MyObservable appObserver = new MyObservable();`

**MyObservable.java**

```
public class MyObservable {
    protected List<Object> observers = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public void addObserver(Object observer){
        observers.add(observer);
    }

    public void notifyObservers(Object data){
        for( int i=0; i<observers.size(); i++ ){
            ((Observer) observers.get(i)).update(null, data);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

I'm testing this on a Nexus One  with Android 2.3.6 if it matters.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Seems I missed a crucial part of the Observer mechanism, apparently one has to call `setChanged()` before `notifyObservers()`. But the thing is, `setChanged()` is protected and thus only visible to any subclass of Observable.

So I guess it's not meant to be used in the fashion I tried to use it, but the hackish subclass below will work...

```
public class MyObservable extends Observable{

    @Override
    public boolean hasChanged() {
        return true; //super.hasChanged();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 14):

BadCash's answer actually didn't work for me, but my issue did stem from the same problem with `Observable`.  Perhaps you're using an older implementation, but I'm on Java 8.  Rather than overriding `hasChanged()`, I had to override `notifyObservers()` to always set itself to be *changed* before notifying:

```
class WorkingObservable extends Observable{
    @Override
    public void notifyObservers(){
        setChanged();
        super.notifyObservers();
    }
};
```

That did the trick for me.  I looked at the source code and it seems that the `Observable` class doesn't call `hasChanged()` method internally to decide whether to notify.  It just checks the `changed` private variable.  This probably could have been implemented better.

Comment: don't forget to override notifyObservers(Object arg) as well, in case you want to pass an argument.